# Find the volume letter of EFI partition

Tags: powershell

I am writing an interactive script and I need the volume letter of the EFI partition. It could happen that there is no letter assigned, in this case I will assign one to it. Since I do not know any method to detect it automatically (please tell me if it is possible), I have decided to list volumes and ask the user the Volume number.
The only command which lists it is the `list volume` command from `diskart`. Is there a Powershell command for this? It would be much easier to parse the object based output than the one from `diskpart`. I have tried `get-volume` but the EFI partition is not shown.

Comment: Just an observation, but it seems server 2019 returns efi partition when using get-volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this command to get the drive letter through the partition, rather than the volume:

```
get-partition | where-object {$_.GptType -eq "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"} | select-object -first 1 DriveLetter
```

Where `{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}` is the GUID for the EFI System Partition in the GPT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition

If you then want to play around with the EFI System Partition object, use this command:

```
get-partition | where-object {$_.GptType -eq "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"}
```

Which will get all partitions visible to the system which are ESP partitions - of which there should only be one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Get-PSDrive cmdlet if you haven't already.

`get-psdrive | where{$_.name -like "[A-Z]"}`